# Display datepicker on tapping on textfield

Tags: ios4, xcode4, uitextfield, uidatepicker

How can I display a datetimepicker control on tap of a textbox?

I have a user interface that has arrival and departure text fields, and when a user clicks on arrival textbox it should bring up a datetimepicker control up instead of a keyboard and the same with the departure textbox.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use `inputView` and `inputAccessoryView` properties of the text field for this. Create the date picker and set it to the input views of the two text fields. Also create another view for the `Done` button and it as their accessory view. You will need that button to dismiss the input view.

The `Done` button must be wired up to function which basically does this –

```
if ( [textField1 isFirstResponder] ) {
    [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
} else if ( [textField2 isFirstResponder] ) {
    [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Another option would be to subclass `UITextField` and override `inputView` and `inputAccessoryView`. This is the way to go when there are loads of them.

**Example**

```
@interface CustomKeyboardAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
...

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIToolbar *accessoryView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *customInput;

- (IBAction)dateChanged:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)doneEditing:(id)sender;
@end
```

In the XIB, Pull out a `UIToolbar` and a `UIDatePicker` but don't attach it to the view. Connect the outlets appropriately. `dateChanged:` responds to changes in the date picker and `doneEditing:` is called when the `Done` button in the tool bar is clicked. Connect them too. The methods are implemented as listed below.

```
@implementation CustomKeyboardAppDelegate

@synthesize window=_window;
@synthesize textField = _textField;
@synthesize accessoryView = _accessoryView;
@synthesize customInput = _customInput;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.textField.inputView = self.customInput;
    self.textField.inputAccessoryView = self.accessoryView;
    ...    
}

...

- (IBAction)dateChanged:(id)sender {
    UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker *)sender;

    self.textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", picker.date];
}

- (IBAction)doneEditing:(id)sender {
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

The last two methods will bloat up as more text fields depend on this picker.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Can you please tell me how I will create a datepicker and set it to the input views? Is this something that I have to do in the Interface Builder or through code?

Comment: Added an example for a single text field. You can do this via IB as I have done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Deepak.I really appreciate it. I also wanted to vote you up but unfortunately that requires 15 reputations:(

Comment: @Deepak how should the toolbar be set up? In my version of Xcode, the toolbar starts with a button on it ("Item"), and it's not linked to anything, and neither dateChanged or doneEditing are ever being called.

Comment: `Item` should be renamed to `Done` and then connected to `doneEditing:`.

Comment: @Deepak what do you mean by "don't attach it to the view" ? I follow your code, that is working fine except for the DatePicker that is present on my view when the view appears. How can I hide it on startup ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Deepak. This has truly saved my day!

Answer (score 11):

Very simple, in `ViewController.h` put the `UITextFieldDelegate` after in `viewDidLoad`.

```
txtFecha.delegate = self;

datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];

self.txtFecha.inputView = datePicker;
```

Comment: Why are you setting the delegate?  It works without it in my case.

Comment: yes, picker is showing but "Done" and cancel button are not showing of that date picker.

Answer (score 3):

*In viewDidLoad of* **ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [txtFieldBranchYear setInputView:datePicker];
}
```

*Add one method in your ViewController*

```
-(void) dateTextField:(id)sender
{
    UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)txtFieldBranchYear.inputView;
    [picker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSDate *eventDate = picker.date;
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:eventDate];
    txtFieldBranchYear.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateString];
}
```

**txtFieldBranchYear** *is an outlet of UITextField*

Comment: This is the right solution for me. Works with 8.2. However I'd probably remove: [picker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]]; to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There's a really useful class I found - the blog post is here: http://www.pietrorea.com/2012/07/how-to-hide-the-cursor-in-a-uitextfield/ but it basically uses the inputView/inputAccessory view as well. The kicker is that the UILabel, at least for what I was doing, was exactly what I needed.

Comment: The link you provided is broken

Comment: It does look like the link is broken. I found a gist here, with the code from the article: https://gist.github.com/mjjimenez/7132551

Answer (score 0):

open date picker on click on textField swift 3.0
add UITextFieldDelegate and 
set delegate on ViewDidload()
    tfDate.delegate = self

```
//MARK:- TextField Delegate
//MARK:-

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

//MARK:- DatePicker
//MARK:-

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
     self.callDatePicker(textField: tfDate)
}
func callDatePicker(textField:UITextField){
    let datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
    textField.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyViewController.handleDatePicker), for: .valueChanged)
}

var str:String = ""
var str1:String = ""
var strStartDate:Date!
var strEndDate:Date!

func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    print("Date :: \(dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date))")
    tfDate.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)


}
```

Comment: repeating another answer