# UIPickerView not scrolling in actionSheet

Tags: ios, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

I've added an UIPickerView into a UIActionSheet. Everything ok, but my picker can't be scrolled to choose a value. Any suggestions?

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
UIPickerView * picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 270)]; 
picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
picker.dataSource = self;
picker.delegate = self;
[actionSheet addSubview:picker];
[picker release];

[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)];
[actionSheet release];
```

Best regards,
Dorin

Comment: Tested this code. It has no issues. What are the `delegate` and `dataSource` methods that you have implemented?

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [array count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [array objectAtIndex:row];
}

Comment: I was putting this code into the method textFieldShouldBeginEditing. I want to enable value selection for a textField when entering in edit mode. In this case my picker seems to be somehow disabled. When I paste the code in didLoad method everything ok.

Comment: so you're trying to associate this to a text field right? can you paste the entire `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` method?

Comment: In the textFieldShouldBeginEditing: method I place the code presented in the topic of my question and I return NO. I placed the same code as action for a button and the picker can be scrolled.

Comment: I am unable to recreate your problem. Code out of `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to what you're trying to achieve is to set text field's `inputView` and `inputAccessoryView`. Setting these will replace the standard keyboard and bring in custom views. This includes the picker view. I happened to write a short example in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074683/display-datepicker-on-tapping-on-textfield/6075062) here. Take a look and see if it helps.