# How to make a UItextField with a UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i wanto to make somethink like this http://tinypic.com/r/33m8vmo/7 . I want to know if it's just a UItextField with a picture in the right or not ? 
and my second question is why i don't have this in my interface builder ? http://tinypic.com/r/121txd5/7 i just have this http://tinypic.com/r/34dgah0/7 ? 
Help me please , i'm a newbie :(

Comment: Similar: http://creiapp.blogspot.hk/2012/11/uitextfield-with-input-from-uipickerview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again it is pretty close to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074683/display-datepicker-on-tapping-on-textfield/6075062) one. You will have to set the desired view (in that example, it was the `UIDatePicker` instance) as a text field's input view. Take a look at the example in the answer and you can model `UIPickerView` instance to be the input view in a similar fashion.

As for the second question, the control you want is a Cocoa control and not a Cocoa Touch control. You will have them available when developing for mac.