# Disable keyboard when

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uitextfield, uistoryboard

When the user clicks on a `UITextField` I am showing a `UIDatePicker` for the input with the code below. But when i do this the datepicker and the normal text keyboard show at the same time. How would i disable the keyboard from displaying?

```
- (IBAction)selectDateBegin:(id)sender {

if ([self.view viewWithTag:9]) {
    return;
}
CGRect toolbarTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-216-44, 320, 44);
CGRect datePickerTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-216, 320, 216);

UIView *darkView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
darkView.alpha = 0;
darkView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
darkView.tag = 9;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissDatePicker:)] ;
[darkView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[self.view addSubview:darkView];

UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height+44, 320, 216)] ;
datePicker.tag = 10;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];

UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44)];
toolBar.tag = 11;
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissDatePicker:)];
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, doneButton, nil]];
[self.view addSubview:toolBar];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveIn" context:nil];
toolBar.frame = toolbarTargetFrame;
datePicker.frame = datePickerTargetFrame;
darkView.alpha = 0.5;
[UIView commitAnimations];}
```

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6075062/662096) link to show picker view using textfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
     [self.textFieldName resignFirstResponder];
   //
   //  Code ...continue,......for display DatePicker
   //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate UIView for your datepicker (with navigation bar having OK and Cancel button) container and then assign it to ***textfield.inputView*** property. For more details refer [*UITextField Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html).

This will load your datepicker view instead of default keyboard.

You will find many more examples on net for the same.

Hope this is what you are looking for.